# Matrices conjugate by an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $7\times 7$ matrices 
$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 a & c & b & c & b & d & d \\
 c & a & b & c & d & b & d \\
 b & b & a & d & c & c & c \\
 c & c & d & a & b & b & d \\
 b & d & c & b & a & c & c \\
 d & b & c & b & c & a & c \\
 d & d & c & d & c & c & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and 
$$N=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 a & c & b & c & b & c & b \\
 c & a & b & c & d & c & d \\
 b & b & a & d & c & d & c \\
 c & c & d & a & b & c & d \\
 b & d & c & b & a & d & c \\
 c & c & d & c & d & a & b \\
 b & d & c & d & c & b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
How do you show that there exists an orthogonal matrix $X$ so that $M=X N X^{-1}$   ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

orangeskid